# Getting an error "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable" while trying to iterate over a url (in Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, iteration, screen-scraping, nonetype

#### I have facing a, NoneType error while trying to scrape data from a page with Python. The lines related to the error are mentioned below:

```
def main():
      url = 'https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=m570.l1313&_nkw=mens+watches&_sacat=0'
      products = get_index_data(get_page(url))
    
       
      for link in products: # Getting error on this line
        data = get_detail_data(get_page(link))
        write_csv(data, link)
```

Comment: Looks like Python?

Comment: So products is None. Have you debugged its assignment? If that is an acceptable return then you need a test for this before your for loop.